# SFSpeechRecognitionTask - 'Use of undeclared type Builtin' error

Tags: speech-recognition, swift3, xcode8, speech-to-text, sfspeechrecognizer

While working with `SFSpeechRecognizer` I encounter this problem:

> Printing description of error.some.instance_type:
>   expression produced error: error: /var/folders/k8/ppsgsylx27b5061mkcw9c7n40000gn/T/./lldb/4446/expr7.swift:1:65: error: use of undeclared type 'Builtin'
>   Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer(bitPattern: 0x101b94360)!.pointee)

What is 'Builtin' here? The error occurs in the following block.

```
recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in ...}
```

Shall the real problem be?

> [Client] {"msg":"Fence: onClientEventRegionState, invalid state", "regionState":"0"}

Here is the [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SpeakToMe/Listings/SpeakToMe_ViewController_swift.html) that I followed. Any hint?

Comment: refer this, https://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/. Its working good for me. @linhcn

Comment: I already checked that out too. The two tutorials are actually the same. It works for the 1st time. The error raised when I switch between view controllers, stop the `audioEngine` and start again.

Comment: I get the same error when I try printing a description of a dict item. At least in my case, this is completely unrelated to SFSpeechRecognitionTask